# Open a web page and write in a text file

Tags: python

I am trying to open a webpage and write the page in a text file. This is the code so far and its not working. Cam anyone give me a general idea about what I am doing wrong?

```
import urllib
opener = urllib.FancyURLopener({})
f = opener.open("http://www.python.org/")
g = open("data2.txt", "w")
g.write(str(f))      # str() converts to string
g.close()
```

All I gets when executing the code is text file data2.txt with below line only:

```
<addinfourl at 43347592L whose fp = <socket._fileobject object at 0x000000000294C480>>
```

Comment: Posting your error traceback would help

Comment: *"It's not working"* is not a sufficient problem description. Please edit your question and state what result you expected, and what result you actually got.

Comment: See the duplicate I linked - you need to call `f.read()` to actually read the response data.

Comment: f.read will display the text in command promt, not write in file as I want. NewBie solution serves the purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  import urllib

  opener = urllib.FancyURLopener({})
  f = opener.open("http://www.python.org/")
  lines = f.read() # you missed this
  g = open("data2.txt", "w")
  g.write(str(lines))      # str() converts to string
  g.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

There are better tools for this job, like [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/). For example

```
import requests

url = 'http://www.python.org'
r = requests.get(url)

text_file = open("Output.txt", "w")
text_file.write(r.text)
text_file.close()
```

Comment: This is good. I didn't know this module.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'grab' module for this too.

```
from grab import Grab

g = Grab()
r = g.go('http://www.python.org')
open('page.htm', 'w').write(r.body)
```